# How to select functions that belong in a given extension in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-extensions

I am trying to compose a `SELECT` from `pg_catalog` that pulls function name, its schema name and the name of extension that created this function.

To pull function list I use (a simplified version)

```
SELECT pg_proc.proname, pg_namespace.nspname AS proschema
FROM pg_proc
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON (pg_namespace.oid = pg_proc.pronamespace)
```

To select extensions I can run

```
SELECT pg_extension.extname, pg_namespace.nspname as extschema
FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON (pg_namespace.oid = pg_extension.extnamespace)
```

Now I am looking for a link between extensions and functions they create when "`CREATE EXTENSION`". The SELECT should ideally produce a list of extension_name, extension_schema, foo_name, foo_schema

Comment: You'll have to include `pg_depend`, which contains dependencies between the extension and its objects.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe This is it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

All credit for this answer goes to LaurenzAlbe who hinted the solution in the comment. The query that lists functions created by an extension is

```
SELECT e.extname, ne.nspname AS extschema, p.proname, np.nspname AS proschema
FROM pg_catalog.pg_extension AS e
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_depend AS d ON (d.refobjid = e.oid)
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_proc AS p ON (p.oid = d.objid)
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ne ON (ne.oid = e.extnamespace)
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS np ON (np.oid = p.pronamespace)
WHERE d.deptype = 'e'
ORDER BY 1, 3
```